# Зависает программа Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

При введении небольших значений num, программа работает, но когда num относительно большое (например 100), то программа ничего не выводит и зависает. При этом этот же код (с изменениями для консоли) в консоли с большими значениями num работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SumInTwoDimensionalArray_WinForms {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox3.Clear();
                if (num < 0) {
                    MessageBox.Show("The number of elements in array cannot be less than 0!", "Error");
                    textBox1.Clear();
                }
                else if (num == 0) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your array is empty!", "Error");
                    textBox1.Clear();
                }
                else {
                    int[, ] arr1 = new int[num, num];
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                            arr1[i, j] = rand.Next( - 10, 10);
                        }
                    }
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                    int rows = arr1.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
                    int columns = arr1.Length / rows;
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                            textBox2.Text += arr1[i, j] + "\t";
                        }
                        textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                    }

                    double[] arr2 = new double[num];
                    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                        double sum = 0;
                        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                            sum += Math.Pow( - 1, i + j) * arr1[i, j];
                        }
                        arr2[i] = sum;
                    }

                    textBox3.Text = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++) {
                        textBox3.Text += arr2[i] + "   ";
                    }
                    textBox1.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch(FormatException) {
                MessageBox.Show("The input is improper!", "Error");
                textBox1.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не глядя в код напомню, что тяжеловесные вычисления нехорошо запускать в потоке UI. Выносите расчёт в отдельный поток, примеров на сайте много постили. http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/multithrwinfrms.xml

Answer (score 3):

[image: пример работы программы]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _number;
    private readonly Random _rand = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //кнопка
        this.button1.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            //если введенные данные неверные сразу выходим
            if (CheckInput()) return;

            int[,] arr1 = await Task.Run(() => GetSquareArray());

            //будем показывать процесс вычисления
            Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(p =>
            {
                label1.Text = p;
            });

            //выводим результат в TextBox2
            textBox2.Text = await Task.Run(() => PrintToTextBox2(arr1, progress));

            //выводим результат в TextBox3
            textBox3.Text = await Task.Run(() => PrintToTextBox3(arr1, progress));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The input is improper!", "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            label1.Text = String.Empty;
            //кнопка
            this.button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вывод данных в TextBox2
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arr1"></param>
    private string PrintToTextBox3(int[,] arr1, IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        double[] arr2 = new double[_number];
        for (int i = 0; i < _number; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < _number; j++)
            {
                sum += Math.Pow(-1, i + j) * arr1[i, j];
            }
            arr2[i] = sum;

            //отображаем процесс
            progress.Report(i.ToString());
        }

        string result = String.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
        {
            result += arr2[i] + "   ";
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вывод данных в TextBox2
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arr1"></param>
    private string PrintToTextBox2(int[,] arr1, IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;

        int rows = arr1.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
        int columns = arr1.Length / rows;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                result += arr1[i, j] + "\t";
            }
            result += Environment.NewLine;

            //отображаем процесс
            progress.Report(i.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Создание массива
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private int[,] GetSquareArray()
    {
        int[,] arr1 = new int[_number, _number];
        for (int i = 0; i < _number; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _number; j++)
            {
                arr1[i, j] = _rand.Next(-10, 10);
            }
        }

        return arr1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверка введенного значения
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true если неверное значение</returns>
    private bool CheckInput()
    {
        bool result = true;

        _number = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        if (_number < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The number of elements in array cannot be less than 0!", "Error");
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
        else if (_number == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your array is empty!", "Error");
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```